# Doubt in linear algebra Question (CSIR NET 2012)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-rank

Let $A$ and $B$ be the $n \times n $ real matrices such that $AB=0=BA$ and $A+B$ is invertible. Which of the following are always true?

1 $\mbox{rank}(A)=\mbox{rank}(B)$

2 $\mbox{rank}(A)+\mbox{rank}(B)=n$

3 $\mbox{nullity}(A)+\mbox{nullity}(B)=n$

4 $A-B$ is invertible.

option 1 is wrong if we take $A=0$ and $B=I_n$ but for rest options i stucked how to think ?

Comment: Your reasoning is incorrect. For one, note that $AB$ can be zero even when $A$ and $B$ are non-zero. For example,
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}
$$

Comment: Also, it's not clear why you believe that $A + B$ being invertible implies that $A - B$ is invertible

Comment: @BenGrossmann - Your counterexample was the one that came immediately to mind. Do people try to look at simple examples anymore?

Comment: @BenGrossmann  ohh yeah this was my mistake. further and i have edited my questions, thanks for comment.

Comment: @BenGrossmann but sir how to approach these kind of questions my reasoning is completely  wrong any hint is appreciable